# Can we construct a totally ordered neighbourhood system from an arbitrary one?

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological space $X$ (some condition needed to be added possibly) and a neighborhood system $\mathscr{U}$ of a fixed point $x \in X$, can we always construct a totally orderd neighborhood system of $x$ (i.e. a neighborhood system $\mathscr{V}$ of $x$ such that for any two elements $V_1, V_2$ in $\mathscr{V}$, either $V_1 \subset V_2$ or $V_2 \subset V_1$) from $\mathscr{U}$?

Comment: By "neighbourhood system", do you just mean any family of neighbourhoods, or a neighbourhood basis?

Answer (score 0):

In a 1st countable space it can be done.  Let U1, U2,.. be a countable
base for x.  Then $U1, U1 \cap U2, U1 \cap U2 \cap U3, ...$ is a nest
(a subset ordered chain) of open sets that is a nhood base for x.